# How to merge data frames of varying sizes and add in blank data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `df1` with 3,000 rows that looks like:

```
  Stabr      Area_name      trucks    FIPS
2    IL        Cook          16.8     72000
3    AL Autauga County       13.8     31088
4    CA       Orange         9.8      32080
5    AZ       Maricopa       30.9     4000
6    CA       Los Angeles    21.2     1022
```

I also have a `df2` with 1,500 rows that looks like:

```
       county      state  FIPS  cars accidents
2        Cook   Illinois 72000  10435     89
3      Orange California  32080  1547      5
4    Maricopa    Arizona  4000   1571     19
5 Los Angeles California  1022   6759    100
```

I would like to add the columns `cars` and `accidents` to `df1` matching by the column `FIPS`. If there is no corresponding FIPS in the smaller `df2`, I would like to add zeroes in the columns `cars` and `accidents. The final product would look like:

```
  Stabr      Area_name      cars     FIPS     cars     accidents
2    IL        Cook          16.8     72000   10435     89
3    AL Autauga County       13.8     31088   0         0 
4    CA       Orange         9.8      32080   1547      5
5    AZ       Maricopa       30.9     4000    1571      19
6    CA       Los Angeles    21.2     1022    6759      100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% select(-state, -county), by = 'FIPS') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(cars, accidents), coalesce, 0L)
```

Output:

```
  Stabr     Area_name trucks  FIPS  cars accidents
1    IL          Cook   16.8 72000 10435        89
2    AL Autauga County   13.8 31088    0         0
3    CA        Orange    9.8 32080  1547         5
4    AZ      Maricopa   30.9  4000  1571        19
5    CA    Los Angeles   21.2  1022 6759       100
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `join`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2,c('cars', 'accidents') := .(cars, accidents),
      on = .(FIPS)][is.na(cars), c('cars', 'accidents') := .(0, 0)][]
#  Stabr      Area_name trucks  FIPS  cars accidents
#1:    IL           Cook   16.8 72000 10435        89
#2:    AL Autauga County   13.8 31088     0         0
#3:    CA         Orange    9.8 32080  1547         5
#4:    AZ       Maricopa   30.9  4000  1571        19
#5:    CA    Los Angeles   21.2  1022  6759       100
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Stabr = c("IL", "AL", "CA", "AZ", "CA"), Area_name = c("Cook", 
"Autauga County", "Orange", "Maricopa", "Los Angeles"), trucks = c(16.8, 
13.8, 9.8, 30.9, 21.2), FIPS = c(72000L, 31088L, 32080L, 4000L, 
1022L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"))

df2 <- structure(list(county = c("Cook", "Orange", "Maricopa", "Los Angeles"
), state = c("Illinois", "California", "Arizona", "California"
), FIPS = c(72000L, 32080L, 4000L, 1022L), cars = c(10435L, 1547L, 
1571L, 6759L), accidents = c(89L, 5L, 19L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
```